# Stop parent [0] when an array stored in a variable is used in an array

Tags: php, arrays

The code below outputs the array in this way:

[image: Screenshot]

We don't want the part highlighted in red, how can we remove this?

```
<?php

$test = array();

$test2[] = array(
    'key1' => '111',
    'key2' => '111',
    'key3' => '111',
);

$test2[] = array(
    'key1' => '222',
    'key2' => '222',
    'key3' => '222',
);

$test['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    $test2,
);

print_r($test);

?>
```

Comment: 0 is the index of the element. All elements in arrays have indexes.

Comment: 0is index value if you dont need like as you said in Image you may used `$test['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    "data"=>$test2
);`

Comment: I think you are trying to do something like this $test['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'meta_query' => $test2,
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_merge()` or a Union operator will do this job well, nothing too tricky about it.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8aec98b158e9cebb0bd67a92c9530592a9907d9e))

```
$test = array();

$test2[] = array(
    'key1' => '111',
    'key2' => '111',
    'key3' => '111',
);

$test2[] = array(
    'key1' => '222',
    'key2' => '222',
    'key3' => '222',
);

$test['tax_query']=array_merge(['relation'=>'AND'],$test2);  // array_merge
//$test['tax_query']=['relation'=>'AND']+$test2;   // array Union operator

print_r($test);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key1] => 111
                    [key2] => 111
                    [key3] => 111
                )    
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key1] => 222
                    [key2] => 222
                    [key3] => 222
                )    
        )    
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over `$test2` and append it to main array.

Updated code:

```
<?php
$test = array();
$test2[] = array(
    'key1' => '111',
    'key2' => '111',
    'key3' => '111',
);

$test2[] = array(
    'key1' => '222',
    'key2' => '222',
    'key3' => '222',
);
$test['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
//    $test2,
);
if (! empty($test2)) {
 foreach ($test2 as $testArr) {
  $test['tax_query'][] = $testArr;
 }
}
print_r($test);
?>
```

[Demo:](http://codepad.org/aHGtQRBg)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
<?php

$test = array();

$test2[] = array(
    'key1' => '111',
    'key2' => '111',
    'key3' => '111',
);

$test2[] = array(
    'key1' => '222',
    'key2' => '222',
    'key3' => '222',
);

$test['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    $test2,
);

$finalStr = str_replace("","[0] => Array",print_r($test,true),1);

echo $finalStr;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding [splat operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) to [Alive To Die's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45325750/5447994) will help you unpack dynamic arrays *(If you are using PHP version 5.6 and above)*:

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/837857)

```
<?php

$test = array();

$test2[] = array(
    'key1' => '111',
    'key2' => '111',
    'key3' => '111',
);

$test2[] = array(
    'key1' => '222',
    'key2' => '222',
    'key3' => '222',
);

$test['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND'
);

array_push($test['tax_query'], ...$test2); // Unpack and add to array with array_push

print_r($test);
```

This method is helpful, if you are not sure about `$test2`'s array count.